# Visual Studio Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am trying to print report in the below format:-

> Details 1:
>
> First row of detail section 1
>
> second row of detail section 1
>
> Details 2:
>
> First row of detail section 2
>
> second row of detail section 2

If we have to use sub reports then what is the purpose of inserting multiple detail sections? I am trying to print report by using multiple detail sections but it is printing rows together:-

i.e:

> First row of detail section 1
>
> First row of detail section 2
>
> second row of detail section 1
>
> second row of detail section 2

Isn't there any property of sections which makes detail section 1 and detail section 2 separate? So that it gonna print all the rows of detail section 1 and then all rows of detail section 2. I used groups but it would be possible if each group would show its separate detail section :). Thanks in advance and I hope it would not be too difficult to print report in this format and I will get the solution from the experts soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement there is no other way except using sub report as it will print according to your output if sub report is not used

Answer (score 0):

Groups may work better than a sub report, depending on the data this will allow like things to be near each other.

```
i.e. 
(Group 1 header: auto_mfr) 
Chevy 
(detail) 
+chevelle 
+corvette
+corsica 
(Group 1 footer) 
there are 3 types of cars
```

and if you don't want to show the group it can always be suppressed